# Unable to use AD group names in pam_winbind.conf after recent updates

Tags: centos, samba, pam, winbind

Since updating my CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 systems I am no longer able to use AD group names in my pam_winbind.conf. I am only able to use SIDS.

The package version samba-winbind-4.10.4-11.el7_8:0. I am unable to find any information indicating this was an expected change or any work arounds/config changes to make it work again.

Does anyone know a way to fix this so I don't need to reconfigure all of the systems in my entire environment?  Thanks

```
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=USERNAME rhost=x.x.x.x  user=USERNAME
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): getting password (0x00000050)
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): could not lookup name: GROUPNAME1
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): cannot convert group GROUPNAME1 to sid, check if group GROUPNAME1 is valid group.
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): could not lookup name: GROUPNAME2
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): cannot convert group GROUPNAME2 to sid, check if group GROUPNAME2 is valid group.
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): request wbcLogonUser failed: WBC_ERR_AUTH_ERROR, PAM error: PAM_AUTH_ERR (7), NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE, Error message was: The attempted logon is invalid. This is either due to a bad username or authentication information.
Jun  1 04:01:05 gmfl1-pv-intr01 vsftpd[17956]: pam_winbind(vsftpd:auth): user 'USERNAME' denied access (incorrect password or invalid membership)
```